# Datasets in ADF are not appearing/loading in Azure Data Factory Studio

Tags: azure-data-factory

When opening Azure Data Factory Studio, our datasets do not appear (couple of 100). If I open the solution in Azure Repos, I can see that they are there. If I open the solution in Visual Studio, again, the datasets are there. Sometimes if we refresh our browser several times over, they appear. If I clear all browser history, cookies, etc, and restart my computer, they 'sometimes' reappear.

If I accidentally close the browser (like I did now), it can take me hours to get the datasets to appear again. Sometimes they just pop back up.

Anyone else experience something similar? I have done a whole load of searches and cannot seem to find any posts with a similar issue (could be my wording?).

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see similar behavior occasionally. There is a "Refresh" button in the upper right hand corner on the Author tab (In Synapse, it is present on the Data, Develop, & Integrations tabs). This will refresh the Assets lists rather than the webpage. If that doesn't work, I would put in a support ticket.

Comment: Thanks @JoelCochran. Last night I sat and refreshed using that button for over an hour. Seems this time that my datasets just don't want to load. Time to get a support plan I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unexpected behavior in Azure Data Factory. As there is no error message, it is difficult to understand reason of problem and difficult to resolve issue.

Providing a [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/) to raise ticket.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone else experiencing the same issue.... turns out it was related to the proxy server. Apparently it was intermittently stripping out the datasets from the header (possibly because there were so many of them - and as they grew in number, so did the frequency in which they were being stripped from the header). Whitelisting ADF apparently solved the issue.